In SQL Athena, how can I get a CSV's creation date and time?
Based on the creation date and time of each CSV file, I want to build a table showing how fresh the data is. In SQL Athena, how can I get a CSV's creation date and time?

I removed the general ANSI/ISO  tag, since this is a very product specific issue.

You can try using the "hidden" $file_modified_time metadata column:
select "$file_modified_time" 
from your_table;

Presto/Trino supports it in several connectors, like the Hive one:

Metadata columns
In addition to the defined columns, the Hive connector automatically exposes metadata in a number of hidden columns in each table:

$bucket: Bucket number for this row
$path: Full file system path name of the file for this row
$file_modified_time: Date and time of the last modification of the file for this row
$file_size: Size of the file for this row
$partition: Partition name for this row


And at least some of this metadata columns are mentioned in AWS docs (like Getting the file locations for source data in Amazon S3 or Considerations and limitations for SQL queries in Amazon Athena)
